# Remove duplicates in the custom trigger

Tags: python-3.x, pip, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a bitbucket pipeline in the python repository.
https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/pipeline-triggers/
In this pipeline I have a custom trigger:

```
  custom: # Pipelines that can only be triggered manually
    first-trigger:
      - step:
          script:
            - pip install library
            - Specific step ...
    second-trigger:
      - step:
          script:
            - pip install library
            - Specific step ...
    third-trigger:
      - step:
          script:
            - pip install library
            - Specific step ...
```

I will call these triggers manually depending on the situation.
I don't like the fact that I have repetitions, I have `pip install library` in each custom step.
Is it possible to make it so that the library is installed every time this no matter what custom step was called?
Or can I add an image before the custom trigger?

```
custom: # Pipelines that can only be triggered manually
image: the image # This step uses its own image
```

Thank you.